# perl : Threads do not die when main process dies

Tags: multithreading, perl

I have a perl program, that spawns several threads. Each thread processees some task (by firing off other system commands etc) and then when its all done, Waits.

Once all threads are done, they fire a signal to Parent process. The parent then loads up new jobs, and signals the threads to go work on these new tasks.

So ideally, this program, would run forever.

Now, if I kill it in command line with `kill -9 MainProgram.pl`, its not killed! I see the output of the jobs the threads are running, and then I also see that after they are done, they getnew jobs and just go on and on...

I am absolutely confounded. If I do a `kill -9 MainProgram.pl`, it is supposed to kill *all* threads it owns, right?
Regardless of what the threads are out doing....

And even if the threads are doing I/O and so they wait for the IO to get done...I would expect the thread to die after its current task is done..but clearly, Main is reloading jobs too, as threads just keep continuing...

Is this kind of behaviour seen in perl ?

EDIT: Some of the code in mainProgram.pl

```
use threads;
use threads::shared;

for (my $count = 0; $count <= $threadNum-1; $count++) {
  $t = threads->new(\&handleEvent, $count) ;
  push(@threads, $t);
}

#Parent thread:
while(1) {
  lock($parentSignal);
  cond_wait($parentSignal);
  getEvents();
  while(@eventCount== 0){
    sleep($parent_sleep_time);
    getEvents(); #Try to get events again until you get some new stuff to process
  }
  cond_broadcast($threadsDone); # threadsgo work on this
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Which threads? Perl has at least two implementations of threading.

Comment: It would be really good if you could post a *runnable* example, so that we can verify the problem. Without such code, only questions remain: Where does `getEvents` come from? Why are you using shared variables instead of semaphores for communication? What are the contents of `handle_Event`?

Comment: What happens if you try killing the PID, rather than the filename, of the process?  kill -9 can't be avoided, after all.  I'd say you're doing it wrong.

Comment: `kill -9 MainProgram.pl` is not proper usage for `kill`.

Comment: @el.pescado, No, it just has one. (Well, there's also Coro, but that's clearly not being used.)

Comment: @amon, Re "Why are you using shared variables instead of semaphores for communication?" Why use semaphores when they're not needed. Do you realize that Thread::Semaphore is built on the same system as user6561 uses?

Comment: @ikegami: you're right, the 5005threads model was removed in 5.10. It amazes me how many there are perl 5.10 installations on production servers.

Comment: @ikegami Yes, I know how Thread::Semaphore is implemented. But sometimes, abstractions can be a good thing (I also tend to prefer Perl over C, and like to use FP and OOP rather than structured programming). If the answer to “why `:shared` instead of T::S” is “because X, Y, and Z”, then we learn more about the program. If the answer is “dunno, what is a semaphore?”, then we can judge OP's skill level more accurately, and a certain class of bugs gets more likely (e.g. I don't see where `$threadsDone` is locked, or `$parentSignal` is signalled)

Comment: @amon, But semaphores and Thread::Semaphore aren't abstractions of signals. Is there an existing abstraction for signals?

Comment: @ikegami You do have a point (and I have the questionable habit of modelling most synchronization problems with semaphores). He might be trying to implement a *barrier* (which can be modelled with a counting semaphore, or a lock variable). But who knows, without the actual code?

Comment: @el.pescado, There was only one model *used* in 5.6 and 5.8 too.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you're supposed to either `join()` or `detach()` on all threads prior to exiting.

From the POD:

> If the program exits without all threads having either been joined or
>   detached, then a warning will be issued.

Source: http://metacpan.org/pod/threads